# Syntax for inserting just time in Oracle table

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I want to create an Oracle table which contains 3-4 columns in which I want to insert just time in one of the columns.

First, I set the datatype of that column to `varchar2` but then I am unable to do any operations on that time.

```
create table attendance(
                 ID varchar2(10),
                 EmpIntime varchar2(10) ,
                 EmpoutTime varchar2(10));
```

I want to insert time in `9:00AM` format and  calculate total time.

Here is [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96975/1)

i want output like that
"emp_in - emp_out = total working hours"

Comment: can you post some sample data with desired output??

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it with `to_date` like below

```
select to_date(emp_out,'HH:MIAM')-to_date(emp_in,'HH:MIAM') from attendance
```

made an sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96975/8 with the hours difference between time

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,this will give you time in hours,minutes and seconds :-

```
create table attend(ID int,emp_in varchar2(10) ,emp_out varchar2(10));

insert all 
into attend values(1,'09:00AM','05:00PM')
into attend values(2,'09:30AM','05:00PM')
into attend values(3,'10:00AM','08:00PM')
select * from dual;

commit;  

select outtime-intime time_difference
from(
select to_timestamp(EMP_IN, 'hh:mi am') intime ,
to_timestamp(EMP_OUT, 'hh:mi am') outtime
FROM attend);
```